# Parsing DateTime from Json error in Flutter

Tags: json, datetime, parsing, flutter

Im trying to get simple DateTime format from Json to my flutter app and however i try i still get this type of format : 2019-03-28 10:06:27.090Z

And im getting this error:

```
E/flutter (27849): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: ApiException 500: Exception during deserialization. (Inner exception: {innerException})
E/flutter (27849): 
E/flutter (27849): #0      DateTime.parse (dart:core/date_time.dart:335:7)*
```

Here is code example:

```
  MyClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json == null) return;
    name = json['name'];
    deletionTime = json['deletionTime'] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json['deletionTime']);
    lastModificationTime = json['lastModificationTime'] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json['lastModificationTime']);
    creationTime = json['creationTime'] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json['creationTime']);
    id = json['id'];
  }
```

Im expecting Json to successfully parse to DateTime.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`DateTime.parse` only accepts `String` arguments. Since value is dynamic check type using `json['key'].runtimeType` and try following solution.

```
DateTime.parse(json['deletionTime'].toString());

DateTime.parse(json['creationTime'].toString());
```

Comment: It need a static value do you know any solution for non-static values?

Comment: Can you provide the example where you're getting the issue?